# biber: Caught signal - SEGV - how to find the problematic bibtex entry?

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

I'M still trying to make biber work after switching my bibtex .tex files to UTF-8 and importing some new entries.

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Config file is '/Users/myname/.biber.conf'
INFO - Logfile is 'Diss.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Diss.bcf'
INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
WARN - Overwriting field 'year' with year value from field 'date' for entry '1991'
WARN - Overwriting field 'year' with year value from field 'date' for entry 'Thomas-Vielma2008'
FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash:
```

I already cleaned a lot in my bibtex file, but I still don't get a bibliography in my pdf, cause biber seems to have a problem with something, but in the .blg log file I don't find a hint on the problematic line.

- Is there another log file which could tell me what's going wrong here?
- How can I fix the problem as quick as possible?
- It seems that biber processes all entries, even if they are not cited - is this correct?
- Is there an option for biber which makes it less "picky" about the entries and still produces at least a bibliography for those who work?
- In the .bib file there are about 3000 entries, so testing by hand for each one is not an option. Is there a way to automate this testing process or print out the last processed entry?

Comment: As long as we cannot see the data, it is basically impossible to help or advise.

Comment: @daleif: thank you for your comment. Neither can I nor do I want to publish my complete references list here online. So my question is: how can I reduce the number of possible entries. Is there no option or verbose log for biber which can at least tell me which line in the .bib file or which entry caused this failure?

Comment: I usually do not use biber. So your only chance is to make a new empty bib file, and the manually transfer each items manually, recompiling each time.

Comment: Comment one half of your bib-file. You can also try the option `--nodieonerror`

Comment: As suggested, don't test one-by-one. Test half then the other half. Repeat for the problematic half until you find the problem.

Comment: You have `INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0`. So you are using them all with something like `\nocite{*}`?

Comment: @cfr: thanks a lot for this comment! Indeed a copy of the nocite command had slipped in my tex file... So I'm right, that biber/biblatex normally only would process the items that are cited, right?

Comment: @Martin I think so. I'm not sure but that's what it seems to me that it seems to do.

Comment: With exported `.bib` files very often the `abstract` is the culprit (sometimes other non standard fields are also non-well formed, in your other MWE you had a `M3` field). Maybe you can suppress the `abstract` being exported - it would be better to make sure only the fields you really need are exported and well formed. A `SEGV` is really nasty and notoriously hard to debug, so the half-half method is probably the only way to isolate the troublemaker.

Comment: @cfr: as I am lazy (and the bib file very large) I found a semi-automatic method (see my answer below) for finding the problematic entry. My programming skills in bash are very very limited, but it worked. :-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks! I was too lazy to do the splitting of the bibliography by hand and found a semi-automated way for solving the problem (see my answer below)

Comment: This error may also appear if the `.bib` file was generated from Zotero and an author field contains only a first name (probably resulting in excessive commas in the `Author` field like shown in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Systematic automated approach for finding the problematic entry

It was suggested to eliminate half of the bibtex entries and this way reduce the number of suspects further.

As I am lazy (and would not know how to do that in an easy way), I used the following semi-automatic method (all done in `Terminal` in `MacOS X 10.6`:

- created a copy of my .bib file in an empty directory
- `mkdir bibentries`
  created a new directory named bibentries
- `split -p @ -a 4 mybibfilename.bib ./bibentries/`
  split my bib file into one file per entry, all created in the bibentries directory
- `cd bibentries`
  switched to bibentries directory
- `for old in *; do mv $old $old.bib; done`
  added extension .bib to all files in bibentries directory
- `rm -rf`biber --cache``
  cleared biber cache
- `sh ~/bin/batchbiber.sh`
  run biber on all files (see bash script below)

#### Script batchbiber.sh (located in my home path `~/bin/` )

(If you don't have `~/bin/` in your home path, you can create it using `mkdir bin`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
# script processes all .bib files in current direcory with "biber --tool"
let n=0 # counter for files
# count files and print their number
for j in *.bib; do 
let n=n+1
done
echo $n bibtex files found
# process files one by one with biber --tool
for j in *.bib; do 
biber --tool $j
done
```

- `grep -i SEGV *.blg`
  search for error message in the created .blg files

... and bingo, I found one entry with this error and easily spotted  the problem: one excessive comma:

```
 Author                   = {Liao,Hongmei and Coyle, ,Thomas W.},
```

:-)

Comment: Neat idea - lazyness is useful ;-). With your example I created a faulty test bib. Running `biber --tool --debug bib.bib` gave me in the resulting `bib.bib.blg` as last lines `[496] bibtex.pm:1029> DEBUG - Parsing namestring 'Coyle, ,Thomas W.'
[496] bibtex.pm:94> FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV` and so identified the faulty entry.

Comment: why does your log file look so different? Mine is missing the very interesting `bibtex.pm:XY>` part - even if I explicitly add the `--debug` option? Having the line number in the .bib file would have made my hack obsolete.

Comment: Probably because I used also the `--tool` option. Also the line numbers don't refer to the bib so are not really useful in this case. The helpful part is the explicit name.

Comment: hm, ok, but I used both options `--tool`  and `--debug` and still get the output like shown in my question above without the explicit problematic text. :-( I've asked a question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230046/how-to-make-biber-1-9-also-print-the-debug-information-in-the-log-file

Comment: `tl;dr` Avoid double commas `, ,` in your author entries such as `Author = {Liao,Hongmei and Coyle, ,Thomas W.},`

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: well, you're exactly paraphrasing the solution I pointed out in the answer to my question: "one excessive comma"

Answer (score 1):

Have tweaked the answer of MostlyHarmless for Windows, cuz the split command with the git bash dont support `-p @` parameter. The batchbiber.sh script works fine after this :)

```
mkdir bibentries
split -t @ -l 1 -a 4 mybibfilename.bib ./bibentries/
cd bibentries
for old in *; do mv $old $old.bib; done
for file in *; do
  sed -z -i "1s/^/@/" "$file" &&
  truncate -s-1 $file
done
rm aaaa.bib
rm -rfbiber --cache
```

Because `-t` makes a seperation after @, we need to add @ at the first position in each file and del the last character (also @) at the end of the file

```
for file in *; do
  sed -z -i "1s/^/@/" "$file" &&
  truncate -s-1 $file
done
```

Because the first file (aaa.bib) will only contain @ we delete it

```
rm aaaa.bib
```