# How to make Biber also print the debug information in the log file?

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber, debugging

I've switched from BibTeX to Biber and I was struggling with some errors.

During those problems (see [biblatex error: invalid format of field 'date' - what's wrong?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229839/biblatex-error-invalid-format-of-field-date-whats-wrong) and [biber: Caught signal - SEGV - how to find the problematic bibtex entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229866/biber-caught-signal-segv-how-to-find-the-problematic-bibtex-entry) ) I noticed that other users seem to get a more detailed output in the log file (see e. g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183645/biber-printbibliography-problem?rq=1).

I also tried to run `biber --tool --debug myreferences.bib`, but I'm still missing those details (like the problematic source text for a FATAL error)

### example of my current project

command: biber -tool --debug references.bib

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.9 running in TOOL mode
INFO - Config file is '/Users/mbg4/.biber.conf'
INFO - Logfile is 'references.bib.blg'
INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'references.bib.blg'
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib'
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
WARN - Datamodel: Entry '2005' (references.bib): Invalid format '2005/12//' of date field 'date' - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry '2002a' (references.bib): Invalid format '2002/12//' of date field 'date' - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Ferri2009' (references.bib): Invalid format '2009/3/25/' of date field 'date' - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Klein2005' (references.bib): Invalid format '2005/9//' of date field 'date' - ignoring
WARN - Range field 'pages' in entry 'Prochazaka1983' is malformed, skipping
WARN - Datamodel: Entry '2006b' (references.bib): Invalid format '2006/2//' of date field 'date' - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Lu2001a' (references.bib): Invalid format '2001/6/15/' of date field 'date' - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'Schubert2002' (references.bib): Invalid format '2002/9//' of date field 'date' - ignoring
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'N.N.c' (references.bib): Invalid format 'Apr\,2003' of date field 'urldate' - ignoring
FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash:
```

### how I'd like it to look like (the FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV line):

```
[496] bibtex.pm:1029> DEBUG - Parsing namestring 'Coyle, ,Thomas W.' [496] bibtex.pm:94> FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
```

### Used software

- TeXLive 2014 on MacOS X
- biblatex v2.9a
- biber 1.9

Comment: You are running biber on your bcf-file. In tool mode you must call biber on a bib-file: `\biber --tool --debug references.bib` (biber will then write a `references-tool.bib` and a log `references.bib.blg`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks, but I did that. In tool mode I always used the .bib files (there were no bcf files, as I did not have a LaTeX document citing my bib files).

Comment: You can find more detailed information in the `.blg` file, the screen output is almost the same in all modes. If you want to go full information, you can use `--trace` instead of `--debug`, but that gave me ~11K lines on a single-entry `.bib` file, so it is easy to get lost in that much info.

Comment: @moewe: again I was too blind :-( Sorry. Could you just post that as an answer, so that I can accept it and we close this question. I thought I had seen that the .blg file contained the same info as the screen output, I should have checked a second time. (If there's a badge for asking a series of trivial question, I should deserve it... aaaaaah)

Comment: Sorry Martin but your output cleary writes " Reading 'Diss.bcf'". It also miss the lines `INFO - This is Biber 1.9 running in TOOL mode` and `INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'references.bib.blg'` so it is not the output of the call I told you to use.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: sorry from me, you're right. I stole my example from my other question from yesterday, so it was not 1:1 what I was asking about. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screen output one gets from running Biber is almost always the same; the difference in whether one uses no option, `--debug` or even `--trace` is found in the `.blg` file.

For a `--tool` run on a stand-alone `.bib` file, you will find the information in `<file name>.blg`, so

```
biber --tool --debug lorem.bib
```

gives a `lorem.bib.blg` with all the log output you want.

Comment: How can I run biker --debug from Texshop while compiling a tex document or do I have to do this from terminal?

Comment: @avocado1 I don't know about TeXshop specifically, but with most editors you can configure the Biber invocation. Then you can add the relevant command-line options there. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 has infos for many editors.

Comment: Thank you, that link was very helpful. Although I solved my problem by deleting the cache, I will add the debug option to biber for future troubleshooting.