# Making Biber talking (verbose)

Tags: biber

I have problems with biber (Version 2.4 and 2.5). The error messages are, however, not very instructive. I would urgently like to know whether there is an option to have biber giving more info, e.g. about the offending entry in the library. As I run biber at the command line I could easily pass this option to biber and ??repair the library.
BTW I have seen [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286706/troubleshooting-for-biber). I does not answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried with the `--trace` or `--debug` options (`--trace` enables `--debug` ).

Comment: This was just the answer necessary. When running the biber --help with win7 the debug option always run out of the window.

Comment: You can redirect such messages in a file: `biber --help > biberhelp.txt`.

Comment: Could we say this is a duplicate of [How to make biber 1.9 also print the debug information in the log file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230046/35864)

Comment: yes, definitly!