# Editing .bib file to fix error

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, biblatex-chem

I'm a fairly new LaTex user and i'm using Biber to compile my list of references. I updated everything to get rid of the incompatible versions of biber error message. This worked for me last time, however now I am getting the error message below.

```
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Rachael\AppData\Local\Temp\fmKc7AzVff\Litreview.bib_9108.utf8, line 5, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name), end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
```

I keep finding threads telling me to go to the line mentioned in the error message (line 5) in my bib file as in the link below, but I'm not really sure what this means are there are no commas on line 5 of my bib file, that is assuming i'm looking in the right place.

([how to find error in bibtex file that biber chokes upon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203312/how-to-find-error-in-bibtex-file-that-biber-chokes-upon))

I'm desperate for some help as my thesis deadline is on friday and I am completely lost as to why it has stopped working now.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

If it helps this is the whole message after trying to compile

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.4
INFO - Logfile is 'Investigating the multiphoton excitation of iLOV and it's      application in Optogenetics.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Investigating the multiphoton excitation of iLOV and it's application in Optogenetics.bcf'
INFO - Found 42 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Litreview.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Litreview.bib'
WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file 'C:\Users\Rachael\AppData\Local\Temp\fmKc7AzVff\Litreview.bib_9108.utf8', skipping ...
WARN - Name "T. Kogej, D. Beljonne, F. Meyers, J. W. Perry, S.R. Marder" has too many commas: skipping name
WARN - Name "S. Chapman, C. Faulkner, E. Kaiserli, C. Garcia-Mata, E. I. Savenkov, A. G. Roberts, K. J. Oparka" has too many commas: skipping name
WARN - Name "P. A. W. van den Berg, J. Widengren, M. A. Hink, R. Rigler" has too many commas: skipping name
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Rachael\AppData\Local\Temp\fmKc7AzVff\Litreview.bib_9108.utf8, line 5, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name), end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
INFO - WARNINGS: 4
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: If it helps this is the whole error

Comment: You didn't input the authors correctly. Authors must be separated by "and": `T. Kogek and D. Beljonne and ...`

Comment: WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file 'C:\Users\Rachael\AppData\Local\Temp\8OPXXxRt8i\Litreview.bib_7008.utf8', skipping ...
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Rachael\AppData\Local\Temp\8OPXXxRt8i\Litreview.bib_7008.utf8, line 397, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name), end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...")

Comment: Sometimes the line number where the error is reported is not the line where the (syntax) error actually occurs. You will have to check the surrounding lines and entries as well. In your example, however, as Ulrike notes you also get helpful warnings about the way you input names (see [How should I type author names in a bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864)).

Comment: Could it be that one of your bibkeys (entry keys) contains a comma or another special character? It would be much easier to find the problem if you could isolate the trouble in your `.bib` file. Make a copy of it and then delete halves of the file and add them back in until you have isolated the problem.

Comment: I have changed the entries and run LaTex Biber and LaTex twice more and the error above came up

Comment: If the error is now reported in line 397 check the entry that lives there and the one below and above. One of them must have something fishy going on, like a missing brace, superfluous commas, missing `=`, ...

Comment: Well at least it is no longer in line 5 but moved on. So it is probably another error. Comment (with %) bibentries until you find the cuprit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, there was a blank entry at the end of my .bib file that I hadn't noticed before. I'll make sure I don't input commas into my authors anymore! Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op didn't show the code, but found the errors by his own ...  (see last comment)